# numpy.datetime64: how to get weekday of numpy datetime64 and check if it's between time1 and time2

Tags: python, numpy

how to check if a numpy datetime is between time1 and time2(without date).
Say I have a series of datetime, i want to check its weekday, and whether it's between 13:00 and 13:30. For example

```
2014-03-05 22:55:00
```

is Wed and it's not between 13:00 and 13:30

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, you could use the `DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time` method to find those dates whose time is between 13:00 and 13:30.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2014-3-1 00:00:00', '2014-3-8 0:00:00', freq='50T')
dates_between = dates[dates.indexer_between_time('13:00','13:30')]
wednesdays_between = dates_between[dates_between.weekday == 2]
```

---

These are the first 5 items in `dates`:

```
In [95]: dates.tolist()[:5]
Out[95]: 
[Timestamp('2014-03-01 00:00:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-01 00:50:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-01 01:40:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-01 02:30:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-01 03:20:00', tz=None)]
```

Notice that these dates are all between 13:00 and 13:30:

```
In [96]: dates_between.tolist()[:5]
Out[96]: 
[Timestamp('2014-03-01 13:20:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-02 13:30:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-04 13:00:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-05 13:10:00', tz=None),
 Timestamp('2014-03-06 13:20:00', tz=None)]
```

And of those dates, here is the only one that is a Wednesday:

```
In [99]: wednesdays_between.tolist()
Out[99]: [Timestamp('2014-03-05 13:10:00', tz=None)]
```